# Can you upgrade from IOS 12 beta to IOS 13 beta?

Tags: ios

When I try to google this I can only find results on downgrading.

Comment: You sure you got that title right?

Comment: @quin Yes and I'm sick of google and search engines suggesting otherwise.

Comment: How can you upgrade from one version of something to the same version? That would involve doing nothing, if you're running iOS 12 beta then to get to iOS 12 beta, do nothing - no upgrade needed

Comment: @Quinn haha, please see new title.